# MVC TempData passing to Jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to assign HTML to TempData as such:

```
     TempData["FilesUploaded"] = "<option value= '" +  file.FileName + "'>" + file.FileName + "</option>";
```

I need to get this value in Jquery. As such, I do the following:

```
    var val = '@TempData["FilesUploaded"]';

    alert(val);
```

What I am finding is that the characters are coming as such:

```
    &lt;option value= &#39;PS Report #36178.pdf&#39;&gt;PS Report #36178.pdf&lt;/option&gt;
```

I tried to do it enclose TempData in @Html.Raw(... but that did not work as well.

Here is what I tried:

```
    var val = '@Html.Raw((string)TempData["FilesUploaded"])';
    alert(val);
```

What is odd is that it doesn't work in that the alert doesn't even come up.

Comment: Now I read the last line. Can you post your version using `Html.Raw`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx) to encode the string as JavaScript:

```
var val = '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode((string)TempData["FilesUploaded"]))';
```

Comment: @NatePat OK now I realized the problem. `Html.Raw` outputted the single quotes, which made the script invalid. The single quotes have to be replaced with `\'` in order for the output to be valid js